# how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I simply get `GET` and `POST` values with JQuery?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
$('#container-1 > ul').tabs().tabs('select', $_GET('selectedTabIndex'));
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

For GET parameters, you can grab them from `document.location.search`:

```
var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

document.write($_GET["test"]);
```

For POST parameters, you can serialize the `$_POST` object in JSON format into a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;

document.write($_POST["test"]);
</script>
```

While you're at it (doing things on server side), you might collect the GET parameters on PHP as well:

```
var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>;
```

**Note:** You'll need PHP version 5 or higher to use the built-in `json_encode` function.

---

**Update:** Here's a more generic implementation:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
```

Comment: Your extraction method doesn’t consider arguments with no value (”?foo&bar=baz“ => {foo:"", bar:"baz"}).

Comment: Nice catch Gumbo! The = in the regex should be made optional: ...snip...(?:=([^&]*))?&?)/g

Comment: 1. Your first GET example doesn't seem to work for me.
2. In your update, your function name has a typo in it

Comment: Have you tried running that in safari or chrome? It creates an infinite loop and crashes the browser. Try it with something as simple as "?p=2"

Comment: @MrColes: Yikes. It has been a while since I wrote this. Since then, I've discovered that Webkit doesn't update the internal position counter of the RegExp object when it is used as a literal. I'll update my answer with the fix.

Comment: I don't think this can match arrays sent via GET.

Comment: @funforums Yup, this implementation doesn't attempt to support arrays. Besides, an array can be encoded in a URL in a number of different ways.

Comment: @AtesGoral That's a pity, because the current implementation already can support arrays in at least a single way, if it did push into a result array instead of making a variable assignment in the loop. I have a working modification for this. Do you think i should edit it?

Comment: This is a beautiful piece of code, thank you so much for this!

Comment: There is no mention of PHP in the OP's question.

Comment: There was a hint: `$_GET`. And the OP accepted this as the correct answer back in 2009, so I think it's safe to assume that the OP's problem had something to do with PHP.

Answer (score 16):

There's a plugin for jQuery to get GET params called [.getUrlParams](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/)

For POST the only solution is echoing the POST into a javascript variable using PHP, like Moran suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use this one http://plugins.jquery.com/project/parseQuery, it's smaller than most (minified 449 bytes), returns an object representing name-value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

why not use good old PHP?  for example, let us say we receive a GET parameter 'target':

```
function getTarget() {
    var targetParam = "<?php  echo $_GET['target'];  ?>";
    //alert(targetParam);
}
```

Comment: Because this is server side solution, and question was about client side / javascript / jQuery side.

Comment: @hkusulja adding insult to injury: even though you affirm it, i still cant see that the question is exclusively server-side.  i feel thick as a tool...

Comment: This script is hideous. Use this if you want your site hacked.

Always escape user entered variables!! DO NOT output $_GET directly.

Answer (score 5):

> Keep it simple

replace **VARIABLE_KEY** with the key of the variable to get its value

```
 var get_value = window.location.href.match(/(?<=VARIABLE_KEY=)(.*?)[^&]+/)[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

With any server-side language, you will have to emit the POST variables into javascript.

**.NET**

```
var my_post_variable = '<%= Request("post_variable") %>';
```

Just be careful of empty values. If the variable you attempt to emit is actually empty, you will get a javascript syntax error. If you know it's a string, you should wrap it in quotes. If it's an integer, you may want to test to see if it actually exists before writing the line to javascript.

Comment: You don't always have access to server-side languages though. For example GitHub pages...

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to gather all the `GET` variables in a global object, a routine optimized over several years. Since the rise of jQuery, it now seems appropriate to store them in jQuery itself, am checking with John on a potential core implementation.

```
jQuery.extend({
    'Q' : window.location.search.length <= 1 ? {}
        : function(a){
            var i = a.length, 
                r = /%25/g,  // Ensure '%' is properly represented 
                h = {};      // (Safari auto-encodes '%', Firefox 1.5 does not)
            while(i--) {
                var p = a[i].split('=');
                h[ p[0] ] = r.test( p[1] ) ? decodeURIComponent( p[1] ) : p[1];
            }
            return h;
        }(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
});
```

Example usage:

```
switch ($.Q.event) {
    case 'new' :
        // http://www.site.com/?event=new
        $('#NewItemButton').trigger('click');
        break;
    default :
}
```

Hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Query String Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery plugins seem nice but what I needed is a quick js function to parse the get params.
Here is what I have found.

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your $_GET is multidimensional, this might be what you're wanting:

```
var $_GET = {};
document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    //handling for multidimensional arrays
    if(decode(arguments[1]).indexOf("[]") > 0){
        var newName = decode(arguments[1]).substring(0, decode(arguments[1]).length - 2);
        if(typeof $_GET[newName] == 'undefined'){
            $_GET[newName] = new Array();
        }
        $_GET[newName].push(decode(arguments[2]));
    }else{
        $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

simple, but yet usefull to get vars/values from URL:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash, hashes = null;
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") && window.location.href.indexOf("&")) {
        hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("?")) {
        hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
    }
    if (hashes != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }
    return vars;
}
```

I found it somewhere on the internet, just fixed few bugs

Answer (score 1):

Use following function:

```
var splitUrl = function() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var url = document.URL.split('?')[0];
    var p = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(p != undefined){
        p = p.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
            hash = p[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }
    vars['url'] = url;
    return vars;
};
```

and access variables as `vars['index']` where `'index'` is name of the get variable.

Comment: This code fails for UTLs like `http://foo.com/?a=b#bar` . It thinks `b#bar` is the value for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
var match,
      pl     = /\+/g,  Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
       search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
      decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
       query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
   urlParams = {};
   while (match = search.exec(query))
    urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record, I wanted to know the answer to this question, so I used a PHP method:

```
<script>
var jGets = new Array ();
<?
if(isset($_GET)) {
    foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
        echo "jGets[\"$key\"]=\"$val\";\n";
}
?>
</script>
```

That way all my javascript/jquery that runs after this can access everything in the jGets.  Its an nice elegant solution I feel.