# Set URL via selected jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, url, select, tabs

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574699/selecting-a-jquery-tab-using-a-parameter-in-the-url) - and using the same getUrlParam.js plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var param = $(document).getUrlParam('tab');
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabs").tabs('select', param);
});
```

With this code I am able to control which tab loads on a given page e.g. `blogs/?tab=tv` loads the tab `#tv` on the /blogs/ page.

However is there a way I can set the URL by clicking on the tabs themselves?

```
<ul id="mediatabs" class="tab-buttons">
<li class="TV"><a href="#TV">TV</a></li>
<li class="radio"><a href="#radio">Radio</a></li>
</ul>
```

i.e. clicking on the TV tab loads `/?tab=tv`?

I guess this is a workaround for the missing bookmarking functionality in Tabs 3.

Comment: are you asking how to add a click handler to the tab?

Comment: @geowa4: Yes, I think he wants to make it so that you can click anywhere in the tab, not just on the `a` link within.

Comment: No - I want to click the tab (the li block) and change the URL. Same as standard tabbing (i.e. #us, #them) - but with the plugin, so I can link in from an external page/site. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're wanting to change a querystring parameter and not the hash of the url (`http://www.example.com/page.html#this-is-a-hash`).  One approach is to use the `select` event which is triggered whenever a tab is clicked.  Something like:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    // TODO: compute the desired url and set window.location.href
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. And I've been trying to make it workable in that way.However. it does not work!!! window.location.href will take you away from tabs and open a new screen.