# Jquery and twitter bootstrap make active tab doesnt work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap js tabs i have to add a class "active" to a li element.

I obtain the hash from the url. I apply the class active to the tab but it doesnt get the focus.

I want to make the second tab active when the url have a certain hash.

Source code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Chumillas/dU458/#example

Comment: Your code works for me but you didn't put bootstrap in it.

Comment: See Manage Resources(2), i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Ok, I saw that now. Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it, i need to set the div of the content of the tab active as well.

Comment: Normally you can just use `$('#mytab a').first().tab('show')`. If it turns out you need to set the `tab-content` div to `active`, check your id for your tab head. You might have spaces in the id.

Answer (score 30):

Also with latest bootstrap-tab.js, you can use following call to select active tab.

Nav Sample:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Get object with link and display call:

```
$('a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
```

Bests, G.

source:[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Comment: And if you are solely using url hashes to select active tab, you can automate the process with this generic code:

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url_hash = window.location.hash.split('-')[0];
      if (url_hash[0] == '#')
        $('#tabs a[href="' + url_hash + '"]').tab('show');
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function (e) {
  var parts = decodeURI(e.target).split('#');
  $(".tabs").tabs().select(parts[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make Bootstrap tabs work, there are two things you have to do to make a tab active:

1. Set the li element to active (class="active")
2. Set the tab div element to active (class="fade in active")

Answer (score -4):

Why are u not using the `select` method instead of changing the class yourself ??

check this, [Selecting a jQuery Tab using a parameter in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574699/selecting-a-jquery-tab-using-a-parameter-in-the-url)

Comment: Doesnt work for me: 

    $('.tabs').tabs('select', 1);

Neither load.

Comment: `select` is a feature of jQuery UI tabs, but is not available in Twitter Bootstrap tabs.