# Highlight search values from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters, highlight

Currently with a site I'm working on, when you search in the global header you are taken to the search results page. Once you are on the search results page, you can see your search in the url. Example: I searched elephant, search-results.html?elephant. I need my search results page to highlight everything on the page that matches the value, and only the value. I don't want the highlight to pick up "search" or "results just after the question mark, the value. The closest solution I've found is this

http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm

but it somehow interrupts my css div headers. Also, (and maybe my brain is just fried from staring at this code for too long) how can I customize this code to read my value? This seems like a solution as well, but I can't get it to work. I used the function highlightSelection() with a body onload and no luck.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-highlighting-selected-text

or even the post here by Coopster, if I could capture the value from the url. I know I can document.write(window.location.search.substr(1)) and it will show me.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/2418.htm

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the contains:
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text

```
$("span:contains('Hey')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

The issue with this you must have a class or something that you want to search specifically, you can do a *:contains but it will end up grabbing every element.

http://jsfiddle.net/dLdb2/

You will need ot grab the $_GET value through either javascript or whatever back end you are using.  Here is a link to grab it with jQuery:

[retrieving $_GET variable in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764778/retrieving-get-variable-in-jquery)

Comment: He/She don't want to highlight the complete sentense, your solution is applying the CSS rule on the entire span.

Comment: I just wanted to add that jQuery's "contains" fn is not case-sensitive by default btw. This may confuse some users depending on the type of search experience they're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a part of the Chad solution to retrieve span that contain the specific text.
Then, instead of applying a CSS rule to the whole HTMLElement, you can retrieve its content with `.html()`, wrap the specific word with specific `<span>` and then update the content with `.html()` method again.

```
// Retrieve and explode URL
var urlParts = window.location.href.split("?");
if (urlParts.length == 2)
{
    // Retrieve all span containing the word
    $("span:contains('" + urlParts[1] + "')").each(function(index, spanElement) {

        var jQSpan = $(spanElement);
        jQSpan.html(jQSpan.html().replace(urlParts[1], '<span class="special">' + urlParts[1] + '</span>'));

    });
}
```

Assuming you have a `.special` CSS class that will highlight the word.

```
.special {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Note: The word in the Javascript function could be injected via PHP or other server side language.

Here is a complete example, assuming your URL is **http://path/to/your/file.php?Lorem**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/jQuery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
            Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression.
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Start when DOM is ready
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var urlParts = window.location.href.split("?");

                // Highlight word if we have a word in parameter
                if (urlParts.length == 2)
                {
                    // Retrieve all span containing the word
                    $("span:contains('" + urlParts[1] + "')").each(function(index, spanElement) {

                        var jQSpan = $(spanElement);
                        jQSpan.html(jQSpan.html().replace(urlParts[1], '<span class="special">' + urlParts[1] + '</span>'));

                    });
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Explanation: When the DOM is ready, the Javascript code will try to extract the part of the URL after the '?' (in our case, this is 'Lorem'). Then, Javascript retrieve, via jQuery, all span containing this word and loop on each span to wrap the word with special span (span with CSS class 'special')

If you change the word in the URL and reload the page, the highlight will change dynamically

Comment: But I don't want specific text. It has to be the sarch from the url.

Comment: You can use the window.location.href property and extract your word. See here for this part, it is quite simple : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764778/retrieving-get-variable-in-jquery

Comment: Yes, window.location.search.substr(1) works. I've used it for a while. I need to highlight though.

Comment: I can't get this to work either. http://www.sitekickr.com/blog/jquery-search-term-highlighting/

Comment: You're missing a ' after the span class tag, I believe. Also, I don't see why Hey needs to be included. span:contains('Hey') Have you tested the code? It makes sense, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: 'Hey' need to be wrapped with span in order to apply a CSS class only on this word (and not the entiere span). $("span:contains('Hey')") will return a group of span containing the word 'Hey'.

Comment: That isn't what I need. If I wanted to highlight "Hey" I would <span color="yellow">Hey</span>, roughly. I need a dynamic highlight according to the url value after the question, and the updated code you used still isn't working anyways.

Comment: Updated my code. I just test it and it is working and dynamic depend on the word o the URL.

Comment: Can you show me a short version of the page you're testing it on? I still can't get it working. Thank you so far, the code looks nice.

Comment: I get the following error when i use the script. The text gets highlighted but every other jQuery function stops: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`
Any idea why is that? @MatRt