# jQuery to trigger event through query string

Tags: jquery, string, events

I have two separate jQuery functions that allow a user to toggle a div's visibility. By defualt, the divs will be in their closed state.  I'm trying to figure out a way to set up links to this page that will open a specific div based on an ID passed to the query string. My jQuery looks like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   //make first div always open

    jQuery(".toggle_container:not(:first)").hide(); 
    jQuery(".toggle_container:first").show();
    jQuery("h6.trigger:first").addClass("active");

    jQuery("h6.trigger").click(function(){
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
      jQuery(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle(300);
    });

    //The second function

    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(".toggleIt").click(function(){
          jQuery(this).next(".hiddenText").slideToggle("fast"); 
            jQuery(this).html(function(i,html) {
                if (html.indexOf('+') != -1 ){
                   html = html.replace('+','-');
                } else {
                   html = html.replace('-','+');
                }
                return html;
            })
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<h6 class="trigger" id='uniqueID"></h6>
 <div class="toggle_container">
TEST
</div>

//and the second toggled container
 <p class="toggleThis tips" id="AnotherID">+</p>
<div class="hiddenText2">
Another TEST
</div>
```

I'd like to add an ID to the query string of a url and have it open the hidden div with the same ID.  I have it structured like this so far...

```
var category = getParameterByName('cat');
var id = getParameterByName('id');

if(id)
{

}
else if(category)
{

}
else
{
    //moving this in here 
    jQuery(".toggle_container:not(:first)").hide(); 
    jQuery(".toggle_container:first").show();
    jQuery("h6.trigger:first").addClass("active");
}
```

I'm getting stuck on this part.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP or another language to create the HTML?..  I would create a hidden field, populated with the query variable, and use the onLoad to open the div if the field has been populated.

Comment: It really needs to be passed through the query string.

Comment: Yes, I agree... You pass it through the query string. Your page creation language embeds it as a value in an HTML input element. jQuery picks that up and acts on it.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. I do need to keep this on the front end though.  I'm fairly sure there is a way to fire a click event, or use a hash + var to trigger this.  Just can't nail it down. Thanks though!

Comment: try looking at this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery