# Getting values from location

Tags: javascript, location-href

I need to get the search query from the search query of the address of the page.

What is the safest cross-browser, and most efficient method of getting the string. for example:

```
q=123&data=true&b=456
//from
http://www.example.com/?q=123&data=true&b=456
```

And is `location.search` available on all modern browsers (IE7+, FF, webkit, opera)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `location.search` is the way to go.

Introduced in JS 1.0, supported by IE 3.0, Netscape 2, Opera 5.12, FF1.0, Konqueror 3.1 and Safari 1.0.

And I guess it is always supported in Chrome considering that the other browsers support it since ages.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Always thought `location.search` was a "new" implementation since ive never seen it used.

Comment: @digitalFresh: I have my information from [ **here** ](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/location.htm#search). It should be reliable. It is in German but I think the icons are self-explanatory ;) The page has been updated last in 2007 so `location.search` is at least there for three years ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a canned answer: [how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery/439578#439578)