# on load of a page read an xml using jquery

Tags: jquery

From 1st page I pass 2 parameters `http://in164263:5050/csm/csminfo.jsp?cfgid=48&filepath=files/csmclientbuckeye.xml`

How to read the request parameter in `csminfo.jsp` and get xml file from `filepath`?

I suppose for reading and parsing xml I can us something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sites.xml", //here i want to read request parameter `filepath`
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

The problem is i am passing the `filepath`on  `onLoad` of page's body, so the spry region tries to load itself through the dataset(which is not yet initialised) but since it does not have the path yet it is not displayed. So how can I get the `filepath` before onLoad so that spry:region gets this filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSP you can use something like this to setup properly your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<%= request.getParameter("filepath") %>",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

Otherwise, if you really ***NEED*** to read the get or post parameters via javascript (jQuery), you can follow this answer :
[how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)

Comment: Not happening `url: "<%= request.getParameter('filepath') %>"` is not able to read the file

Comment: Once that your JSP page is parsed / loaded (in the browser) you should see `url : "files/csmclientbuckeye.xml"`, what do you see?

Comment: Check these examples http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/getparam.html to get rid of the `getParameter` method

Comment: before using this reading xml, I was passing my req params to a function where i was able to fetch `files/csmclientbuckeye.xml` from  `filepath` this is what i was using `<body onload="getConfigDetails('<%= request.getParameter("cfgid") %>','<%= request.getParameter("filepath") %>')">` so `"<%= request.getParameter('filepath') %>"` should get me the path, but is not working

Comment: Can this be a apex problem? i mean, why are you using `"<%= request.getParameter('filepath') %>"` and not `"<%= request.getParameter("filepath") %>"` ? JSP should parse only the text inside the `<%` and `%>` and ignore the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax() with dataType set to XML if the server, from which you are fetching data doesn't send proper content-type. Then in success callback first argument is your XML.

```
 $.ajax('path/xml', {
   success: function(xml) {
     var $xml = $(xml);
     alert($xml.find( "title" ));
   }
 });
```

Or use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) inside success callback.

Comment: The path to the xml file is coming from previous page as url variable, how can i access that variable in jquery?