# retrieving data from db based on php's $_GET var with jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Disclaimer**

I have searched for duplicates, but I can't seem to find them. I am surprised because this seems to be a big issue. I most likely am missing something big though.

**Problem/Question**

I am having the `userid` passed into through the url via `php`, `myOtherScript.php?userid=1`. How can I get that variable to be passed via `ajax` so that I may query the database with that `userid`, echo it out and return it to the page?

This is in `global.js` file

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myScript.php",
    data: "userid="  - This is what I need: $_GET['userid'] - ,
    success: function( data ) {
        $('#myDiv').html( data );
    }
});
```

**Solution**

WIth the help of bstakes and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) answer, I was able to figure it out with this function: (top answer)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using the search attribute of the window.location object.

If the url is http://www.mysite.com/display.php?userid=7 window.location.search will return "?userid=7". You will obviously need to remove the leading "?", but be aware that if there are additional GET paramaters, separated with ampersand '&', those will be included as well.

So, with a bit of additional Javascript, you can split on the '&', which gets you an array of "key=val", then you can spilt on the equal sign and create an object with {key : val}. Then you could use that object to access the query string params.

```
var qs = window.location.search.substring(1),
    pieces = qs.split('&'),
    i,
    qsObj {},
    tmp;
for ( var i in pieces ) {
   tmp = pieces[i].split('=');
   qsObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location for additional information on the window.location.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myScript.php",
    data: "userid=<?php echo intval($_GET['userid']); ?>",
    success: function( data ) {
        $('#myDiv').html( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that a safe/best practice type way of doing it? Does jQuery have a function to pull data from the url?

Comment: @Phil: The safe practice is to use sessions, store user_id (and maybe some other data) in `$_SESSION` when user successfully logs in, and get it from there.

Comment: This solution does not work. You can't have `PHP` in a `JS` script.

Comment: @Phil: did you try it? Delete your downvote and try it first -.-

Comment: I meant to remove it, but I can't because you didn't edit it. It isn't the solution, but that doesn't mean you should get a downvote...

Comment: @Phil:I think this 100% is solution! Just try it and you'll see!

Comment: I want to keep the `PHP` and the `JS` separate. You can't do that with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to move the script inline on the PHP file then you echo out the $_GET['userid'] in the data area of your ajax call.

just found this: [how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the JS seperate, put it in a function that accepts the user id...

```
function do_something(user_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myScript.php",
        data: "userid=" + user_id,
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#myDiv').html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Then just call `do_something($_GET['user_id']);`

Comment: This only works if you bring the function in the `.php` script. I want to be able to keep it in a separate `JS` script and still retrieve the `$_GET` vars.

Comment: Well I wouldn't recommend doing it this way but in javascript you can pick out the query strings using good old `location.href`. There's some jquery plugins to make this easier, try http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object