# jquery check if URL has a querystring

Tags: jquery, string, url

If its the first time visiting the site and no querysting has been added or if there is only one querystring attached to the url '?hos' like http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos=somevalue, then i need to apply the if condition..the else condition is working fine..How do I check to see if there is a query

```
$(".hospitalDropDown").change(function(e){
  currentURL=$(location).attr('href');
  if((currentURL == 'http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx' or (....)) {
    window.location.href= 'http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx'+'?hos='+$(this).val();
  } else {
    window.location.href = ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx': currentURL +'&hos='+ $(this).val(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 22):

I think you'd like this value:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
```

If your URL was "http://www.google.com/search?q=findme", then the above `queryString` variable would be equal to "?q=findme".

You can check if that is non-empty to see if there is a query string or not.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure about the entire query string, but this will help you check if there are individual variables in the query string:

```
var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

document.write($_GET["test"]);
```

This question has some more answers that might point you in the right direction:

[how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".hospitalDropDown").change(function(e){
        if(location.href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
            window.location.href= 'http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx'+'?hos='+$(this).val();
            }
            else{
                window.location.href = ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://hospitalsite/events/Pages/default.aspx': location.href +'&hos='+ $(this).val(); }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code to get the query string:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
if (results == null)
    return "";
else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

if this function returns null then there is no query string, you can directly call this function.