# How to get parameter in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Need help..how can I get the parameter pass by the ajax..

```
url: test.htm?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I want to get the value of b.

Comment: please explain the scenario in detail

Comment: What do you mean? Does this question provide you with any answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getQueryString(queryString) {
  var result = {},
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}

var query = "test.htm?a=1&b=2&c=3"
var myParam = getQueryString(query)["b"];
alert(myParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

the "dirty" way is to `location.search.split("&b=")[1].split("&")[0];` but that's not reusable and I'll get flamed about it for sure...

the better way has been answered here before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/1238884