# How to retrieve GET variable from ajax response in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get URL parameter with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

I have a form that posts data over ajax. The response comes back in the form of GET variables in the URL. For example if there was a failure of writing the form data the return address would be: http://example.com/?error=1

How would I check for this using jquery. Right now when I do a console.log on the msg variable I just get the html output of example.com (which I guess makes sense). I need the GET variables though. How would I achieve this?

```
$('#wp_email_capture').submit(function(e){
    var email = $('#wp-email-capture-email').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/",
      data: "wp_capture_action=1&wp-email-capture-email=" + email
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg)
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Check this post: [how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery

Comment: Well I didn't end up finding a solution to this problem so I ended up outputting json from my php file instead.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX by default will return the *content* from the request.  What you want are the *headers*.

If you are being given a return address of `http://example.com?error=1`, then it means this is being returned as a redirect header.

To get the header information from an AJAX request, that has been answered here:
[jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

Comment: Just tried this out but it loks like the headers it reponds with do not contain the GET variables:  Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 22:19:50 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
X-Pingback: http://example.com/xmlrpc.php
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 22:19:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT