# Jquery To get url paramaeters

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Say if,i've a URL like this **update** [test](Http://www.test.com?q=1.)

I want to check if URL has a parameter q.

Can i use $get() ,to do this.

```
If(urlparamerter == q)
{

   do some thing

}
```

Is there any jquery build in function which does this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no jQuery Built in function to do this. You can use the following function, found from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158301/344304)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {

    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(window.location.search);

    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

}
```

To get the `q` parameter just call it like

```
var qvalue = getParameterByName('q');
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use this function by passing `url` instead of using `current page's url` modify the function like follwoing

```
function getParameterByName(name,url) {

    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(url);

    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

}
```

and then you can call it like

```
var qvalue = getParameterByName('q','www.test.com?q=1')
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/XhtSb/1/)

Comment: :Check my updated URL.How do i do that there? When i pass a string to function parameter then i alert qvalue,i get null.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/XhtSb/1/

Comment: :Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/AbwGb/.I'm trying to validate whether the given text is valid url format,it is not working.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/hsefQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to check out the jQuery [URL Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) plugin. It's a pretty straight-forward way of interacting with the url and queryString data:

```
var q = $.url().param("q"); // Gets the q parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

For GET parameters, you can grab them from `document.location.search`:

```
var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

document.write($_GET["test"]);
```

Or, here's a more generic version:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
```

Or, better yet, grab them using PHP:

```
var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>;
```

This answer is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery).