# Getting Url Parameters as Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

lets say my site has url http://www.akbrowser.tk/ds/?q=http://www.chess.com&r=http://www.blackle.com

(the two parameters are URLs)

I now want to get two javascript variables on the site, with the values of the two urls. (so the first variable would be the chess.com, and the second would be blackle.com  [of course it would have the http and all, but I can only post one hyperlink])

how would I do that?

I saw some other similar questions on this site, and the poster gave a long solution that I didn't understand (I think it had something to do with find a '=' and take everything after it) but in this case it would give "http:// www.chess.com&r=http://www.blackle.com [without the space]" as one of the variables.

I also saw another post with multiple parameters like mine, but the poster gave a long solution so since I didn't understand it, I couldn't really make it do what I wanted it to do.

so can someone help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: thanks guys, but on all of the links i don't understand which are the variables? (see comment below on the '1 answer' thingy

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function getQueryParam(href, paramName) {
    var query = href.substring(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    var params = query.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var param = params[i].split('=');
        if(param.length > 1) {
            if(param[0] == paramName) {
                return param[1];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(getQueryParam('http://www.akbrowser.tk/ds/?q=http://www.chess.com&r=http://www.blackle.com', 'r'));
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out, but I don't get why the URL that i gave is in the program. (chess.com and blackle.com were two arbitary examples)

Comment: he's just putting that in there for illustration. you'd normally grab it from the href.

Comment: @user1380792 replace it with window.location.href

Comment: "is in the program" you might want to say, "I don't get why my URL is a string literal"

Comment: hey, guys, why you are downvoting post? please comment

Answer (score -1):

```
function gup(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}

 var qString = gup("q");
 var rString = gup("r");
```

What this does is do a regex to find whatever [name] you pass in to the function.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand. What are the 2 variables? is it name or results or regex?

Comment: sounds like you need to learn to read javascript a little better based on your question. This is a function that retrieves values based on the query variable names. The result would only ever be results[1] since that's what the function returns (unless not found).