# javascript copy form from one page to another form on another page

Tags: javascript, forms

Is it possible to copy values from a form on page x to a form on page y using javascript. The data is the same but just different pages and different applications?

Comment: I have looked into jquery clone() but examples are on a single page. I would like to copy from one application to another application.

Comment: In what way does the JavaScript from one page "see" the other page?  It would need to be able to access it somehow in order to modify it.  Is one of them perhaps within an iframe of another or something like that?

Comment: you can use a cookie - but `$_SESSION` on the server side would be the normal way of doing this

Comment: I don't totally understand the question - are you going from one page to another? Are you doing cross tab bleeding edge? If you're doing data transfer between tabs I would use something like pubnub to "beam" the data live to other computers (as separate tabs are rarely connected at all).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Using AngularJS you could use "search" variables and then plug these into the form. Using normal javascript you may be able to use a # with the data. Using PHP + normal javascript (more secure) you can send a POST to the page (which is a PHP page) and have the page, if the POST params with your values exist, put a javascript fragment on the page setting the values of the form when the page is done loading.

Cookies are also always an option :)

**[EDIT]**

After discussion, here is the solution to the question: [GitHub](https://github.com/kidovate/copyformdata)

Comment: This is an excellent lead. I am going to see how I can do it so when the second page opens, the values are already filled in. If it works, I will be the happiest man alive today.

Comment: How are you going to do this? Which method? I gave you like 4 lol. If you do get it to work please accept.

Comment: I think you're using the PHP method - you can do this either by injecting the POST values directly into the HTML (I.E <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["myValue"]; ?>"></input>) but you'll want to be sure to 'sanitize' the POST variables, check if there's no cross site scripting (no <script> tags) as someone could easily inject code into your site this way (put script in the POST paramater)

Comment: What I am trying to do is to insert info in a non-user friendly form that was previously designed as the people who made it don't want to change it. So I am mirroring the same form but making it more user friendly. Thus my form would be collecting data to insert in the bad form.

Comment: I am also looking at Firefox InFormEnter where I would submit data to it and open the other form and just click to autofill as I do not have control over the form.

Comment: If you want to do this you can use a JavaScript page load to load the existing form into the view after the page has loaded. you can then use jquery to fill the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23997/discussion-between-mpora-and-christian-stewart)

Comment: Hi, Did my answer solve your problem? If so please accept. If not, let me know and I'll help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cross-tab JS is not allowed. I am not sure about bleeding-edge apis.

Theoretically, it is possible to do via local storage with a same-origin restriction. But you'd better don't mind this option.

Also, try to play with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just from one page to another you can append the data to the request as POST (with PHP) variables, or a simple query string (GET) and read them once the page has loaded/populate relevant fields - if the second page is loaded directly from the first.

If it needs to be retained until an unspecified time (when the user may have gone to other pages in the interim) you could look into using cookies.

[how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var myValues;
   if (document.cookie) {
      // get your values onLoad
      myValues = document.cookie;
   } else {
      // set your values
      myValues = "..." // your values
      document.cookie = myValues;
   }
}
```