# jquery context variables

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to understand how jquery handles context. I have this code:

```
var formHtml;

jQuery.get("form2.htm", function (data) {
    formHtml = data;
});

alert(formHtml);
```

What it does, it gets data from the `form2.html` page and I am setting the formHtml variable to that data so that I can use it somewhere else but when I alert that I get undefined. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The `.get` is asynchronous, so the code moves forward to your `alert` before your formHtml is set.

Comment: Well for one, the get will take a moment to complete. The formHtml may not change until after you alert it.

Comment: May I suggest you reading [jQuery's faq](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions)?

Comment: `alert(formHtml);` is occuring before the `.get` has finished. Ajax is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.get()` is an asynchronous call. jQuery.get() uses [AJAX](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications) to fetch the value from the server side. That means the execution of the javascript statements will continue after sending the request to server without waiting for the response from the server.

[AJAX](http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/ajax) stands for `Asynchronous JavaScript and XML`.

When response from the server comes back the callback method registered with the `post` method gets called.

So by the time the server request comes back the `alert` statement would have already executed. Since you have declared the global variable `formHtml` and not initialized it, its value is `undefined` that is what you are getting in your alert.

Comment: Now I know this is not working: https://github.com/kidovate/copyformdata. I had asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695651/javascript-copy-form-from-one-page-to-another-form-on-another-page and someone offered it as a solution. When I tried it out nothing worked.

Comment: Do you want to copy the value from one form to anoter?

Comment: Yes. Specifically from one form on page "a" to another form on page "b" where I do not have control over page "b".

Comment: It is not possible unless you store the values from the page `a` in a shared space.

Comment: Thank you. What are some shared spaces do you have in mind? I have implemented some code to alter a bookmarklet and I was looking to explore other possibilities.

Comment: Is value stored in the database which you have access to? other wise I'm afraid it is not possible.

Comment: I am dealing with a very bad designed form that users do not longer want to use and the owner of the form wont change it. So I decided to a design a custom form to mirror the other form and I would transfer the values over to the other form once the custom form is submitted.

Answer (score 4):

`ajax` is asynchronous, so the alert is executed before the call has finished

Answer (score 1):

`alert(formHtml);` will be executed before `formHtml = data;`

Answer (score 1):

As said by **Leeish** -> `Well for one, the get will take a moment to complete.`

You can use `.ajaxComplete()`:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   alert(formHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var formHtml;

jQuery.get("form2.htm", function (data) {
    formHtml = data;
    alert(formHtml);
});
```

Like said before, `jQuery.get` is an asynchronous method. The callback function will be executed later when the response is received.

```
jQuery.get("form2.htm", function (data) {
    formHtml = data;
    alert('response received!');
});
alert('request send!');
```

You will see 'request send!', then 'response received!'.

Answer (score 0):

`form2.htm` is loaded asynchronously. Your `alert` runs before the callback you passed to [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is called so `formHtml` has not been given a value yet.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.get()` is asynchronous operation and your anonymous will call after finishing ajax call but during ajax request your alert is showing data so it is showing undefined