# Using GET when creating an html page for phonegap?

Tags: php, html, get

I'm converting my web-app to a single page html app ready for making one code base for phonegap native apps as well as the web app.

Currently members of the site have QR codes that allow people to connect to their pages via the homepage of my app ie the QR code connects to the homepage, and then a $_GET strips out their details and opens their page.

Now that the index page is HTML, not php, I'm wondering is this can still be done? ie how do you deal with $_GET on a non php page?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the query string from location.search

I got a code somewhere to do this, but I'm too lazy to find it so:

for $_GET take a look at this:

[how to get GET and POST variables with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery)